# C# Reading a specific line from large data .txt file

Tags: c#, .net

I have a txt file in which X,Y coordinates are saved. Each lines contains different coordinates, as a result each line might have different size from the previous/next line.

The size of the file is too large to open it uses ReadAllLines function ( File can be larger than 10-50GB ). I have seen many answers talking about File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(n).Take(n).ToList();

My questions are, will this method load the file on RAM or it will load only the lines inside the Take(n) function?
If there is no way to access directly a specific line in txt file, would it be a good idea to transfer the data into a database table where access is easier?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think the Did you try the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-6.0) answers the question

Comment: TL;DR; The documentation (see comment by @fredrik):
When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The microsoft documentation says: "The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned"

I Think you suggestion will load only the lines in the RAM.
Test it and use the memory debugger to check it [Microsoft Doku](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2022)

Maybe you can remove some overhead of this big file ...